# Regex for HTML form validation start without space

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I have a form field in which I want to allow 1 to 50 letters, numbers, and spaces in it. Just not start with a space and ends with a space. (Or, alternatively, if it starts with a space, it's not counted toward 50.)

I have something like:

```
^[^s][a-zA-Z0-9_ ]{1,50}[^s]$
```

But something like "AB" now doesn't pass, because nothing match the {1,50}.

**EDIT:**

The regex is for the HTML input element `pattern` field.

Comment: ´[^s]` means *match anything but `s`* - guess you want *anything but `\s` (whitespace)*. And that you can do with `\S` (capital S) - `^\S[a-zA-Z0-9_ ]{1,50}\S$`.

Comment: And more to the point - I guess you're looking for more like `^\s*[a-zA-Z0-9_ ]{1,50}\s*$` which **allows** white space in the beginning and at the end, without them being included in *the 50*. (The logic of) Your regex **requires** white space in the beginning and the end.

Comment: `^[^\s][a-zA-Z0-9_ ]{1,50}\b$` or `^\b[\w ]{1,50}\b$` https://regex101.com/r/lE5hS9/1

Comment: @ClasG Your description sounds about right. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
^\b[\w ]{1,50}\b$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/lE5hS9/1)

Comment: This works. Though it doesn't permit space before and after. It's more stringent, but it works for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

My comment as an answer ;)

```
^\s*[a-zA-Z0-9_ ]{1,50}\s*$
```

This regex will **allow** entry of white space in the beginning and at the end without **requiring** it as your attempt (kind of) did.

Regards

**Edit:**

Combine Tims answer with this and you avoid *space only*:

```
^\s*\b[\w ]{1,50}$\s*
```

This forces the string to have a word boundary - i.e. must contain a *word character*.

Comment: I tried it. Unfortunately, that makes one space by itself pass the test as well (within pattern attribute of an input element), which should not be allowed.

Comment: Actually you could combine Tims answer with mine and get exactly what you're looking for. See edit.

Answer (score 1):

Or with minimal use of regex:

```js
function myFunction() {
    var input = document.getElementById('myInput').value.trim();

    if (input.length < 1 || input.length > 50) {
        document.body.innerHTML += "wrong lenth";
        return false;
    }

    var re = /^[\w ]+$/;

    if (re.exec(input) !== null) {
        document.body.innerHTML += input + " is valid";
        return true;
    } else {
        document.body.innerHTML += input + " is not valid";
        return false;
    }
}
```

```html
<input id="myInput">
<button onclick="myFunction()">Test</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. Though I need it to be in the pattern field. (HTML 5 Constraint Validation API) Sorry about wasn't being clear.